# An require_once in another require_once - some functions work, others don't - PHP

Tags: php, include, require

This is a tricky one to explain.  So I'll bullet point it:

- I have a file that **require_once** all my settings files and classes ...I call it start.php
- I **require_once** that file in my index.php
- My index.php file then I **require_once** a another file called home.php

This scripts works perfectly on my localhost server.
Now my issue presents itself when I try it on my online server and some functions seem to be working while others are not and I get this error:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function update_display() in /xxxxx/home.php on line 146

Now I know "Fatale error" is because I require_once, but what I don't understand is why some functions seem to be working while others do not?
Also worth mentioning that if I do require_once in my home.php file, it says that I am declaring the function twice!

Any help, much appreciated.

Comment: Are you using file paths everywhere? (No http://)

Comment: @Pekka - I'm just using relative paths ie functions/start.php

Comment: most likely the wrong files are getting included, so try using abs paths (convert relative path to absolute by prepending `dirname(__FILE__) .` to it (note: dot is for concatenation with the relative path that follows in the code)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use such useful functions as [get_included_files](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-included-files.php) and [get_include_path](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-include-path.php) to diagnose a problem. Just print their result somewhere (for instance in /xxxxx/home.php just before update_display call).
Also you can list defined functions using get_defined_functions().
This will help you to clear up what's actually loaded.

Comment: Thanks for that.  After using the get_included_files, for some strange reason one the files that I included, was not gotten from the same file as all the others.  Anyway, it helped me find the error, so thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

have you tried to convert php starting tags from:

```
<?
```

to:

```
<?php
```

? HTH

Comment: Thanks for the input, but I always use <?php ?>

Comment: in your webhost's ftp you may have a file called error_log or something, read if there is some error at end of the file